# creating form inside webforms.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am newbie to Asp.net webform. How to create a form inside asp.net webform page .I tried to create as follow but its not working

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

           <form name="user_detail">
          </form>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please explain: it's not working.

Comment: Why you want two forms?

Comment: look at this :) http://code.runnable.com/UhC31SICZHEKAAOF/submit-a-form-in-asp-net

Comment: Why Nested Forms? ,if you really want to implement form inside a form Go for someother control which has postback url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175986/is-nested-form-possible

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the

`<form name="user_detail">
  </form>`

you can just name your main form as `user_detail`